# My program cannot run with "command not found" error

Tags: command-line, gcc, c

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu 11.10.

I wrote the following code in C with the text editor and saved it as HelloWorld.c in Documents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I started the Terminal and enter the following commands:

```
cd Documents

gcc HelloWorld.c
```

A file called a.out, which, after some search on Google, is the executable. I entered this command:

```
a.out
```

But I get

```
a.out: command not found
```

Which step did I do wrongly?

Comment: Do not forget to make it executable, use `sudo chmod 777 a.out`

Comment: @NickShvelidze Compilers pretty much always set `+x` for you; you do not need to `chmod` the executable produced by a compiler. The only common situation where `gcc` fails to make it executable is if it's creating the file in a filesystem that doesn't support or allow it (in which case `chmod` immediately afterwards would fail too). Also, `777` should be avoided. There is no need to make it readable, writable, and executable by all users; if it *were* necessary to run `chmod`, then `chmod +x a.out` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since you're running an executable in the current working directory, you should prefix it with `./`. So for your program run it as `./a.out`.

#### Explanation

The terminal searches for executables in `$PATH`. This is a Unix [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) that lists directories containing system binaries (such as `ls`, `echo`, or `gcc`). If you call an executable that's *not* in a `$PATH` directory (such as `a.out`), you need to indicate its absolute path in the file system.

In the terminal `.` is a synonym for the current working directory, thus `./a.out`. You could equally well call `/home/yihang/Documents/a.out`.

Comment: To further elaborate on this, the "./" serves as a "right here", command. It's a bit redundant, but useful in the sense that you know you'll be executing something.

Comment: You may also need `chmod u+x a.out` to allow the system to execute it.

Comment: Now I get it with "./". The program runs fine without chmod. Thanks.

Comment: @yihang: Please consider to mark this question as answered, by clicking the gray/green circle on the left side of the answer you like most.

Comment: @Ruben Bakker:  Actually, it's not at all redundant.  Unlike Windows, Linux does not default to looking in the current, or default, directory.  So, if it's not in the path, you need to specify the directory, whatever it is.

Answer (score 10):

When you run commands on Linux it searches all the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable, and if it doesn't find the command there then you get the message you've seen.

Typically it looks like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

That means it will look first in `/usr/local/bin`. If it doesn't find it there it'll look in `/usr/bin`, and so on.

In fact, this is very similar on DOS/Windows: there's a variable called `%PATH%` that does exactly the same thing.

The *difference* is that, on Windows, the current directory is also searched. Unix considers this bad because a local file (such as malware) can override important system programs accidentally.

If you prefer that though, you can make Linux work the same way by adding `.` to the path:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

(That says set `PATH` to `.:` plus the existing contents of `$PATH`.)

It ends up looking something like this (it may be different on your machine):

```
PATH=.:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

If you'd rather not do that, you can simply run each program by specifying the directory explicitly:

```
./myprog
```

or

```
/home/username/myprog
```

Comment: If you do add `.` to `PATH`, **always** add it last.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, the a.out is created by default because you didn't specify a name for the executable.  Try this instead:

```
gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld
```

Once you do that, you should be able to invoke it by (as Sunil suggested) prefacing "HelloWorld" with a dot-slash(./):

```
./HelloWorld
```

Here's a link to an article that explains a little bit about why the a.out gets created: [Writing and Compiling C Programs on Linux](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/c_compiling_linux.html).