# Bitnami Lamp on Ubuntu mysql command not working in terminal

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, mysql, lamp

Installed a fresh Bitnami Lamp from here https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/installer
Now the `localhost` and `phpmyadmin` in browser is working but when in terminal i typed `mysql` command in `lamp/mysql/bin` directory it is saying

> mysql command not found.

I am very new to the linux env and have recently installed ubuntu. 
I don't know if i should save the PATH but it seems to me the path problem will only be if it works inside the bin directory. But it does not work there.

`which mysql` doesn't do anything at all

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. can you check it using `which mysql` and please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1168364/edit) your post with including the outpur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My program cannot run with "command not found" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110803/my-program-cannot-run-with-command-not-found-error)

Comment: @MartinThornton I think they are two completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your lampp/mysql/bin using terminal
after that use this

```
./mysql -u root -p
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: that works, i don't know hwy

Comment: `mysql -u root -p` doesn't work but ./mysql -u root -p does

Comment: Because your mysql not installed in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin but into lamp directory.